# Dynamic count in Tableau

Tags: dynamic, tableau-api

Hi I am trying to count the number of distinct values in a column.
For Ex:
Columnn1
v1
v2
v1
v2
v1
v3
.
.

Gives the value
Column1..... Count
v1................40
v2................25
v3................17
and so on.
Now I know that you can create a calculated field with all the possible values and then use the count(Distinct) method to get the individual totals.
This is fine for columns with limited possible values.
But I have a columns which takes many possible values and also I want to repeat it in many columns so I dont want to type the values again and again.
So if any of you could show how to dynamically do this that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What makes a row distinct? If each row is a distinct unit you're trying to count, then the following should work:

Drag Column1 into Rows shelf. Then bring in Number of Records into the view.